# Pose Bone Drivers

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]

BLEND:
https://github.com/enzyme69/blendersushi/files/1625959/bone_driver_006_2018_01_12_12_18.zip

Not sure if Blender has some kind of method of connecting Bone Animation or Action and ability to drive the Action based on a value.

Some kind of Advanced Bone Driver.

I would like to know both ways.... if possible.

What I am doing here using Animation Nodes where I have 2 x Armatures.

Armature A should be the dummy. It stores animation within certain length. Basically some kind of Action, that I would like to apply to Armature B, the real bone.

I like AN to be the bridge.

What I am wondering here is: is there a quick and easy way to transfer all the attributes from Armature A to Armature B, since they are all pretty much identical, and I am really here wanting to control the Frame or absolute Time of Armature B.

Comment: Blender mechanism is called Action Constraint, I think this is what I am trying to do:
https://vimeo.com/171554048

Comment: Blender doesn't seem to have a nice way to read bone fcurves or set bone transformations. So what you are trying to do might be hard to create. I will try to find an easy way to do this and get back to you.

Comment: I see... perhaps there are some unexpected complications that I do not yet see. Reading some other conversations.

Armature can have many bones, each bone can have or not have attributes and f-curve... hmm.. yeah, basically I am trying to recreate Bone Action Constraint in nodes, but I wanted to know the possibilites and limitations at the moment. 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31812/how-can-i-access-bones-animation-data-action

Comment: This the complications I was talking about. We will have to classify and filter fcurves to bone and transformation channels, then for each bone, identify all its parents and multiply all of their transformation matrices to get the current location, rotation and scale of the bone. While it can be done, I don't see an easy/efficient workflow for using them in our node based system.